# How can I "uncheck" a checkbox field with Laravel Application testing?

Tags: php, integration-testing, laravel-5.1

In Laravel 5.1 according to http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/testing#interacting-with-your-application I can use:

```
$this->visit('/register')
     ->type('Taylor', 'name')
     ->check('terms')
     ->press('Register')
     ->seePageIs('/dashboard');
```

But is there any way to uncheck a checkbox? (No matter if it is checked or not).

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the underlying DOM crawler (Symfony).

- you reference the form by the text on the submit button
- you can check or uncheck elements
- finally you submit the form

  ```
  $form = $this->getForm('SUBMIT');
  $form['single_cb']->untick();
  $form['multiple_cb'][0]->untick();
  $form['multiple_cb'][1]->tick();
  $form['multiple_cb'][2]->tick();
  $this->makeRequestUsingForm($form);
  ```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Comment: You could also select form by ID with: `$this->crawler->filter('form#form_id')->form();`

Answer (score 1):

You can now also use

`$this->uncheck('#my-checkbox');`

Comment: Link to the [source code of `uncheck()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/125758c5997331a724f424a2b67c2fdd53ca46cb/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Testing/InteractsWithPages.php#L606).